# Perl chomp turn multiple digit number into 1 or 0

Tags: perl

I have a situation where I need to read a file full of numbers in Perl. This works fine in and of itself, but when I try to chomp each line it's turning the numbers that used to be 5 or 6 digits into either 1 or 0.

Ideas?

I need to chomp the numbers to assemble file paths with them, so the carriage returns are a problem.

Comment: Can we see your code? Sounds like you are capturing the return value of chomp as your line. That isn't how you should do it.

Comment: Don't forget about this resource available at your command line: `perldoc -f chomp`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're not using `chomp` like

```
$line = chomp($line)
```

are you? The return value of `chomp` is the number of characters removed from the input, and *not* a chomped line of input. Instead you just want to say

```
chomp($line)
```

Comment: Thanks. That would be the problem.

Comment: `chomp`'s interface is a design mistake. It takes many people for surprise. [`Text::Chomped`](http://p3rl.org/Text::Chomped) however does the right thing.

Comment: Why does `Text::Chomped` require an arrayref instead of a list?