# How to do perl inline regex without setting to a variable?

Tags: regex, perl, replace

Normally if you wish to change a variable with regex you do this:

```
$string =~ s/matchCase/changeCase/;
```

But is there a way to simply do the replace inline without setting it back to the variable?

I wish to use it in something like this:

```
my $name="jason";
print "Your name without spaces is: " $name => (/\s+/''/g);
```

Something like that, kind of like the [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace) function in PHP.

Comment: The interface of the substitution operator is not a good design. [(I've already said something like this once today.)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319170#comment-3443516) There's talk on [p5p](http://www.socialtext.net/perl5/index.cgi?p5p) to add a flag to it so it returns the changed string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Revised for Perl 5.14.

*Since 5.14*, with the `/r` flag to *return* the substitution, you can do this:

```
print "Your name without spaces is: [", do { $name =~ s/\s+//gr; }
    , "]\n";
```

---

You can use `map` and a lexical variable.

```
my $name=" jason ";

print "Your name without spaces is: ["
    , ( map { my $a = $_; $a =~ s/\s+//g; $a } ( $name ))
    , "]\n";
```

Now, you have to use a lexical because $_ will *alias* and thus modify your variable.

The output is

```
Your name without spaces is: [jason]
# but: $name still ' jason '
```

Admittedly `do` will work just as well (and perhaps better)

```
print "Your name without spaces is: ["
    , do { my ( $a = $name ) =~ s/\s+//g; $a }
    , "]\n";
```

But the lexical copying is still there. The assignment within in the `my` is an abbreviation that some people prefer (not me).

For this idiom, I have developed an operator I call `filter`:

```
sub filter (&@) { 
    my $block = shift;
    if ( wantarray ) { 
        return map { &$block; $_ } @_ ? @_ : $_;
    }
    else { 
       local $_ = shift || $_;
       $block->( $_ );
       return $_;
    }
}
```

And you call it like so:

```
print "Your name without spaces is: [", ( filter { s/\s+//g } $name )
    , "]\n";
```

Comment: Or you could use a lexical variable without using `map`: `print "Your name without spaces is: [", do{my $a=$name; $a=~s/\s+//g; $a}, "]\n"`

Comment: @mobrule:I was adding that as you typed. :D

Comment: Accepted this one since it has more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
print "Your name without spaces is: @{[map { s/\s+//g; $_ } $name]}\n";
```