# Inline regex replacement in perl

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

Is there a way to replace text with a regex inline, rather than taking the text from a variable and storing it in a variable?

I'm a perl beginner.  I often find myself writing

```
my $foo = $bar;
$foo =~ s/regex/replacement/;
doStuff($foo)
```

where I'd really like to write

```
doStuff($bar->replace(s/regex/replacement/));
```

or the like, rather than using a temporary variable and three lines.

Is there a way to do this?  Obviously when the regex is sufficiently complicated it makes sense to split it out so it can be better explained, but when it's just `s/\s//g` it feels wrong to clutter the code with additional variables.

Comment: Dupes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321400/how-to-do-perl-inline-regex-without-setting-to-a-variable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting from perl 5.14 you can use [Non-destructive substitution](http://www.perl.com/pub/2011/05/new-features-of-perl-514-non-destructive-substitution.html) to achieve desired behavior.

Use `/r` modifier to do so:

```
doStuff($bar=~s/regex/replacement/r);
```

Answer (score 14):

You really can't do what you want because the substitution function returns either a `1` if it worked or an empty string if it didn't work. That means if you did this:

```
doStuff($foo =~ s/regex/replacement/);
```

The `doStuff` function would be using either `1` or an empty string as a parameter. There is no reason why the substitution function couldn't return the resultant string instead of just a `1` if it worked. However, it was a design decision from the earliest days of Perl. Otherwise, what would happen with this?

```
$foo = "widget";
if ($foo =~ s/red/blue/) {
    print "We only sell blue stuff and not red stuff!\n";
}
```

The resulting string is still `widget`, but the substitution actually failed. However, if the substitution returned the resulting string and not an empty string, the `if` would still be true.

Then, consider this case:

```
$bar = "FOO!";
if ($bar =~ s/FOO!//) {
   print "Fixed up \'\$bar\'!\n";
}
```

`$bar` is now an empty string. If the substitution returned the result, it would return an empty string. Yet, the substitution actually succeeded and I want to my `if` to be true.

In most languages, the substitution function returns the resulting string, and you'd have to do something like this:

```
if ($bar != replace("$bar", "/FOO!//")) {
   print "Fixed up \'\$bar''!\n";
}
```

So, because of a Perl design decision (basically to better mimic `awk` syntax), there's no easy way to do what you want. However you could have done this:

```
($foo = $bar) =~ s/regex/replacement/;
doStuff($foo);
```

That would do an in place setting of `$foo` without first assigning it the value of `$bar`. `$bar` would remain unchanged.

Comment: Technically, `s///` returns the number of substitutions made (or the empty string if that's 0).  But if you don't use `/g`, obviously that can't be more than 1.

Comment: Theoretically, you could have a modifier for `s///` that tells it to make a copy of the string, (possibly) modify the copy, and return that new string.  I think I've seen that suggested before, but it hasn't (yet) made it into Perl, and it might never be added.

Answer (score 5):

```
use Algorithm::Loops "Filter";

# leaves $foo unchanged
doStuff( Filter { s/this/that/ } $foo );
```

Comment: `List::MoreUtils` has the same function called `apply` which is probably a better name for it.  `Filter` makes me think of `grep` type functionality (probably because `grep` is called `filter` in most languages).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `do { }` block to avoid creating a temporary variable in the current scope:

```
doStuff( do {(my $foo = $bar) =~ s/regex/replacement/; $foo} );
```

Comment: So apparently what I want isn't possible without either clutter or my own function.  (It's easy enough to write that, but that makes it harder for others to scan -- they won't know the semantics of my function.)

Comment: The whole idea was to clarify the results. Doing what you're showing still uses a temporary variable `$foo`, and makes the program harder to understand.

I believe what the poster really wanted to do was avoid having to create a temporary `$foo` to do put in the doStuff function.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?:

```
my $foo = 'Replace this with that';
(my $bar = $foo) =~ s/this/that/;
print "Foo: $foo\nBar: $bar\n";
```

Prints:

```
Foo: Replace this with that
Bar: Replace that with that
```

Comment: That saves a line by putting the definition together with the substitution, but still uses a temporary.  Is it impossible to avoid this?

Answer (score -1):

There is yet another way: Write your own function:

```
sub replace (
    my $variable = shift;
    my $substring = shift;

    eval "\$variable =~ s${substring};";
    return $variable
}

doStuff(replace($foo, "/regex/replace/"));
```

This wouldn't be worth it for a single call, and it would probably just make your code more confusing in that case. However, if you're doing this a dozen or so times, it might make more sense to write your own function to do this.