# Getting the file extension and uppercasing it (Perl)

Tags: regex, perl

How can I make this piece of my code terser (in one line) but still understandable.

```
 ($ext) = $ARGV[0] =~ /(\.[^.]+)$/;
 $ext=~s/^.//s;
 $ext=uc $ext;
```

It gets the file extensions, remove the dot and then uppercase it.

```
in: asldaldjlajdlk.torrent
out: TORRENT
```

Answer (score 4):

I think I'd probably use something like:

```
my $ext = ($ARGV[0] =~ /\.(\w+)$/) ? uc($1) : undef;
```

Adjust `undef` to be whatever you'd like the default value of `$ext` to be when the regexp fails to match.

Answer (score 3):

You've chosen a pattern that will not always match.

I therefore suggest using a ternary to be able to explicitly specify your undefined value.

```
my $ext = $ARGV[0] =~ /\.([^.]+)$/ ? uc($1) : '';
```

Comment: +1, I was thinking along the lines of `(my $ext = $ARGV[0]) =~ s/^.*\.([^.]+)$/\U$1/;`

Comment: My first thought was to do `(my $ext = uc $ARGV[0]) =~ s/.*\.//;`.  However that would change the definition of what's an extension.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

$v is your input

```
($m = uc $v) =~ s/(\w+)\.(\w+)/$2/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing my answer, this is discussed here: [Inline regex replacement in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330882/inline-regex-replacement-in-perl)

The furthest I got was this:

`($ext = uc $ARGV[0]) =~ s/^.*\.([^.]+)$/$1/;`

Comment: No, it won't. Plus it has the side-effect of altering `$ARGV[0]`.

Comment: I just realized that. Updating my answer, but it's not a bit improvement.

Comment: \1 won't work on the RHS of a substitution in Perl. $1 is used instead.

Comment: @Slade: It will work, but it's discouraged because it's ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

I think I would ignore the possibility that a file name may not contain a dot, and write

```
(my $ext = uc shift) =~ s/.*\.//
```

- If there is a dot in the name, this leaves `$ext` set to the upper-cased file extension (everything after the last dot).
- Otherwise `$ext` is set to the whole upper-cased file name.